# Where can I find a pulley

Tags: how-to-survive

On what island can I find a pulley?

Comment: I completely understand deutschZuid.  I did that on purpose though for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just played through the game twice. I could only find a pulley Santa Barbara. It is the last/largest island.